# Angular Production build error "ERROR in Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angular

While I am creating the production build using `ng build --prod` while compiling But working perfectly fine in case of development mode, How can I solve this?

I am using `.toLowerCase()` in many places how can i identify where exactly this method is causing error or is this method is actually causing error because if it is causing error then it should be present in case of development as well. Please help how i identify what is exactly causing the issue

getting below error:

```
chunk {} runtime.acf0dec4155e77772545.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.82b46379c162ae4d74cf.js (main) 147 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.4503f8e2df6ab08e9ee5.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.c90132e48ef115ac4fd0.css (styles) 3.91 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.f8926a8840b29b228587.js (scripts) 587 kB [entry] [rendered]
Date: 2020-12-21T17:39:25.893Z - Hash: cfeb9076f180357d8675 - Time: 41679ms

ERROR in Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

> package.json

```
{
 "name": "project4",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~10.1.4",
"@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
"@angular/common": "~10.1.4",
"@angular/compiler": "~10.1.4",
"@angular/core": "~10.1.4",
"@angular/forms": "~10.1.4",
"@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.4",
"@angular/router": "~10.1.4",
"alife-file-to-base64": "0.0.4",
"amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^4.4.0",
"apexcharts": "^3.23.0",
"aws-sdk": "^2.784.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
"crypto-js": "^3.3.0",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.6",
"ngx-cookie-service": "^10.1.1",
"ngx-image-cropper": "^3.2.1",
"ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
"ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
"ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.4",
"@angular/cli": "~10.1.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.4",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "~5.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.0.2"
}
}
```

> angular.json

```
{
 "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
"project4": {
  "projectType": "application",
  "schematics": {},
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/project4",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": true,
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css",
    "node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js",
          "node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js"]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb",
              "maximumError": "10kb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "project4:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "project4:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "project4:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "tsconfig.app.json",
          "tsconfig.spec.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    },
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "project4:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "devServerTarget": "project4:serve:production"
        }
      }
    }
      }
     }
    },
   "defaultProject": "project4",
    "cli": {
     "analytics": false
     }
    }
```

Comment: Do you use something like `environment.someThing.toLowerCase()`?

Comment: Show us both of your environment files.

Comment: @BojanKogoj not directly i am using this by assigning value to a variable and then using toLowerCase()

Comment: @RandyCasburn i am not comfortable sharing the environment files but yes this is for sure that both the environment file has same exact same keys

Comment: OK, without sufficient information to determine the issue, this question lacks debugging details. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Is this the whole error you are getting? is there a way you could post the log file or at least the portions related to your build?

Comment: @MarioPerez yes, this is the whole error i am getting, I am not getting anything other then this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by changing optimization to `true`. I do not how it worked but it eventually solved the issue. By turning it off will there be any effect on prod environment?

Answer (score 0):

Build your application on local machine in development mode with "optimization": true set in your angular.json. This is needed for more convenient debugging.

Open your style.css file generated in the dist folder and inspect it for errors (in case you're developing in docker container, copy this file from the container to host).

When you find syntax errors like this: enter image description here try to match the erroneous code in the generated style.css with your source code and fix the issue / issues there.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with **Angular 11** when I ran the `ng build --prod` command:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):

Error: /../../example.component.less Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

so I found in the *example.component.less* file that some css attributes were not defined and the angular compiler in *production mode* is more stricted, look at:

```
.card-container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 40%;
    border: ; <<< Here <<<
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
```